# Can I optimize a set of JS (combine to one) and still dynamically load certain modules w/ requireJS?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm hoping to load jquery, jqueryUI, underscore & backbone, and non-AMD jquery plugin's via RequireJS 2+'s shim, then dynamically load JS for certain view.

So instead of combining everything as 1 big JS file, can I...

- selectively combine something as 1 big JS
- something else as another big JS (for another complex view), and
- left something else uncombined (for certiain widget) (maybe compressed only)?

Is this possible?  p.s. When shall I consider using [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [use a build file](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) when optimising your project then you can specify exactly what modules need to be processed.

The [`modules` section of the build file](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L237) will be the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

Longer:

You could basically include anything you wanted in any way you want to. The only problems you might face are that the scope of the AMD-loaded libs is local within the define 'handler' function. As far as I know at least.

so I think it is like so:

```
define([somefile], function(something){ something == 'stuff from somefile.js'; });
somefile == undefined
```

What you could do though is:

```
<script etc..."backbone.js"</script>
define([somefile], function(something){ 
    window.something == 'stuff from somefile.js';
    Backone is defined. 
});
window.somefile == 'stuff from somefile.js';
```

So it is possible, but you'd have to set variables from within the define code to a global one, for example window.etc.

And I think you could use Almond in high performance situations. At least according tho their website. You could write some test code on jsperf.om though.